# What a BEFORE trigger can do that an AFTER trigger can't and conversely

Tags: sql, triggers, database-trigger

I've read a lot about these type of trigger and what I understood until now is that they can do exactly the same things, the difference is more about "taste" than what they really are able to do.

So what I'm asking is: is there something that a BEFORE trigger can't do compared to an AFTER trigger and conversely? Am I missing something?

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using. I suspect it is oracle

Comment: This mainly depends on the DBMS, they might have different restrictions.

Comment: I was just studying sql, so it is not related to any particular dbms, it is more about the standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **before** trigger allows you to set action before any other action is done.

Just imagine a table with a foreign key column which is not nullable. You might insert this depending row **before** you insert the row which needs this FK to be set.

You could prohibit any action at all (no changes allowed to key tables...)

You could check for existance and do an update instead of an insert

and many more...

Answer (score 2):

To Expand a little on @Shnugo's answer, note my comments are more specific to sql-server but I believe principles hold true for other rdbms that have the triggers.

What can `BEFORE` (or instead of) do that `AFTER` cannot

Say you have a `BEFORE` trigger on a blank table with an identity column that does nothing/no insert.  To get a similar result in an `AFTER` trigger you would have to delete the inserted records.

Let's walk through inserting records with the different triggers. If `BEFORE` trigger is enabled and you do 100 inserts, but trigger doesn't actually insert them, then you disable the trigger and do an insert you will be at identity 1.

Do the same thing for an `AFTER` trigger and when you insert after you will be at 101.  Because the records where actually inserted, but then deleted.

So a `BEFORE` trigger can stop an action completely where as an `AFTER` has to try to undo an action to get a similar result in the data.  Complex Validation?  Or in Shnugo's example more common insert a parent record before inserting a child to that parent so a foreign key constraint error doesn't occur.

What can an `AFTER` trigger do that a `BEFORE` cannot.

Use the identity column on an insert statement.  In sql-server the special table `inserted` in the same `BEFORE` trigger as above will return `Identity = 0` instead of `Identity = 1`. Where an `AFTER` trigger will have `Identity = 1`.  So in the `BEFORE` you could avoid a foreign key constraint by inserting a parent and in the `AFTER` you can do the opposite you can insert a child record with the proper foreign key.